# Application bypassing proxy setting

Tags: penetration-test, android

I am testing an Android application and found that it is bypassing/disregarding the proxy set (Burp proxy with root certificate installed and Certificate pinning disabled).

I can intercept https traffic from other applications but this application seems to not use the proxy.

Could anyone provide advice on how to intercept traffic for such applications?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rooted device you can force the app to go through the proxy with some iptables rules.

You may need to override any pinned certificates within the apk.

Answer (score 1):

While GnP's answer is correct, I have another possible method for you. You could create a new wireless hotspot with your PC (maybe you need an additional USB dongle), setup a transparent proxy like [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org) and connect your phone to it. AFAIK, this works best on Linux-PCs.